# Netlify CMS multiple environment merging strategy

Tags: reactjs, netlify, netlify-cms

Brand new to netlify/netlify-cms.
This is probably going to sound like a very stupid question.  My team is very interested in using netlify for a website rewrite to replace WordPress.
However, there is one thing that I am stuck on understanding.
I'm hoping someone can help me wrap my head around it.

For this project, we would like to have multiple environments.  For the sake of simplicity lets just say a staging environment and a production environment.
It's my understanding that by using different config.yml files for each environment, I can achieve having content from each environment site committed to the appropriate branch.

This leads me to where I'm struggling.
This staging environment is going to be used for testing.
Testers are going to throw whatever they need to in there to complete their test case.
For instance, to test blogging, they may create a completely fake blog entry.  That will result in that entry being committed into the staging branch in git.

When we deem the new features ready to go live, I would want to merge the new features of the site up to production, but I certainly don't want to merge any of the testing content.
Being that those are committed to git, how can I PR changes from staging into production without also pulling the test content into production?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, pretty stupid question.  Answer from the netlify gitter chat.

> @jansselt you can use an additional branch, there's no limit there. Have your testers use a separate "testing" environment.